# Laptop slowing due to heat: how to know, how to solve?

Tags: laptop, performance

My laptop sometimes slows down unexpectedly on long uses.

I suspect that the laptop temperature is going to high, then the CPU (or the chipset) is slowing down to avoid damaging the hardware. I can even feel the heat through my table.

Is there any way to "detect" if my hypothesis is right?
If true, what can I do to prevent it?

Some information:

- My computer is a Dell Latitude E6400 (Core 2 Duo, 4Gb RAM, Intel GMA
  4500 *`<low cost low perf low productivity>`*, SATA 7200 RPM hard
  drive) running on Windows 7 SP1 x64.
- I'm heavily using it as a development computer (CPU, disk and memory 
  are always is high load), and, unfortunately, I can't simply reduce
  the number of running apps/services.
- Using Speccy, I see this average temperatures (Celsius / Fahrenheit):

  - motherboard : 70 ºC / 158 ºF
  - CPU : 60 ºC / 140 ºF
  - hard drive : 45 ºC / 113 ºF

Comment: @nhinkle: just curious, why did you removed the speccy report ? I added it at the end of the question, in a code section to avoid visually lengthy post. I supposed some hardware guru would like to check a specific data in the report. Normal users, then, see the begin of the question, which is the essential part...

Comment: it was way more info than necessary, and largely irrelevant. It also slows down the page load for everyone who loads the page. If you want, you could upload it to a pastebin or something like that, and provide a link.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'll keep the pastebin option if someone requires more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a heat-related problem, too.

Normally I would suggest to select a less aggressive power-profile, but you stated that you need the performance at all cost.

Ultimative low-price solution: Try to hoist up the back of the laptop to increase the airflow below the laptop. I often just grab a book or (if available) two rubbers of same thickness. Helps a lot under high CPU-load.

If it helps, but not enough, look for "laptop cooler stands" at your favourite HW-supplier - they are fairly cheap, but do yourself a favour: Buy one with a big fan instead of one with two or more noisy mini-fans.

BTW: Cleaning the air inlets from dust should be a standard maintenance task.

Comment: I've already hoisted a bit the laptop... but it's not magical. Your advises are precious, but do you know if there is a way to check my hypothesis ? Are the temperatures monitored high values ?

Comment: The CPU temperature is rather low wheras I'd consider the Mainboard temperature as rather high (maybe it's the chipset temperature - in that case it's ok again). But you also stated that these are *average* values. If in heavvy use the CPU may peak very fast to higher temperatures. Does this tool you use allow to record the temperatures for a period of time? If so, I'd make a note when the performance decreases and afterwards compare these times with the recorded temperatures.

Comment: average at high charge... +/- 5°C

Answer (score 0):

Download coretemp and monitor your CPU speeds.

Thermal throttling will be visible

Also, use crystaldiskinfo to check if there are any warnings for your HDD (Highly unlikely though)

EDIT: Your temps seem to be in the slightly higher range, depending on ambient temperature.

But, they arent high enough to cause throttling

Comment: `Thermal throttling will be visible` : can you explain me ? I'm not sure to understand how to see that... in fact, I don't know how to interpret the data

Comment: forget it... i misread the answer... you want me to check if the clock speed falls to detect if the temp is to high ?

Comment: yes..  IF there is thermal throttling, the clock speed will fall. (Make sure you are in full performance mode though)

Comment: After an hour of running prime95, full defrag (smart defrag 2) and some other high charge job, the system goes into what I call "unresponsive"... the mouse was lagging, nothing respond correctly, etc. However, the temperature never goes over 72° C, and the cpu clock did not fall.    Don't know what to check now :(

Comment: 72 under load is quite acceptable.  Thats the end of my debugging knowledge though